# O(1) Constant time solution example?

Tags: c++, loops, big-o

I have a task which requires calculating a frog jumping from position X to a position greater than or equal to Y, given a fixed distance each jump (D).

E.g
X = 10; Y = 85; D = 30; Answer = ((Y-X)/D) = 3;

The solutions complexity must be **O(1)**.

The obvious solution didn't work:

```
int diff=Y-X;
int jumps=diff/D;
```

Because if jumps returns a double which rounds down, this will not be equal to or greater.

I can use a while loop:

```
int diff=Y-X;
int jumps=0;
int jumps_counter=0;

while(jumps<diff)
{
 jumps+=D;
 jumps_counter++;
}
```

However clearly this isn't going to be O(1), instead O(x-y)...

Whats the best way to solve this?

Comment: Round it up instead. Use [ceil()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/)

Comment: Round *up* instead? By using [`std::ceil`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil)?

Comment: If you are not allowed to use `ceil`, use `#define CEILING(X) (X-(int)(X) > 0 ? (int)(X+1) : (int)(X))`. Taken from `http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/ceiling-function-c-programming-637404/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obvious solution would be to round it up.

```
int diff = Y-X;
int jumps = std::ceil((double)diff/D);
```

This is an O(1) operation and avoids looping to find the required number of steps.

Answer (score 0):

in integer arithmetic

```
int jumps = diff / D + (diff % D ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

With D = 30 size jump, starting from 10 would give you

10 ---> 40 ---> 70 ---> 100

So total 3 jumps..

You need a simple formula : `ceil((y-x)/d)` where ceil(z) is smallest integer greater than z

in python it would be like

```
import math
math.ceil( (float)(y-x)/d )
```

Comment: The formula isn't 3*(Y-X)/D. 3 is just the output of (Y-X)/D